# Easy way to take a comment thread to chat sooner?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If I expect a comment thread to require several back-and-forths, is there an easy way to take it to chat sooner than the 8th reply (or whenever it is that the site automatically suggests you take it to chat)?

I know I can manually create the chat room and then post a link to it in the comments, I'm just wondering if there is a more convenient way that I'd missed.

Comment: At this time, there is not... I would suggest creating a new chat room and then posting your own comment saying `@User1: let's move this conversation to http://chat.stackexchange.com/room-for-you-and-me` or something to that effect.

Comment: @studiohack: thanks, this helps a lot. =)

Answer (score 5):

Found the relevant code:

```
var c=this.jDiv.find(".comment-form");

c.find(".discussion-info").length ||
  ($("<div style='margin:12px 0 3px; font-weight:bold' class='discussion-info'>Please avoid extended  discussions in comments. Would you like to <a href='#'>automatically move this discussion to chat?</a></div>")
  .find("a").click(function(a){
    $(this).unbind("click");
    a.preventDefault();
    b.ajax({url:"/posts/"+b.postId+"/move-discussion-to-chat", data:{fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey},type:"POST"},"when trying to move the discussion to chat",c).done(function(a){a.success?window.location.href=a.message:StackExchange.helpers.showErrorPopup(c,a.message)})}).end().prependTo(c),a.remove())}}});
```

So, we can see that it is doing a POST to `/posts/{postId}/move-discussion-to-chat` and `StackExchange.options.user.fkey` is passed along; this would require an user script to replicate. Simply because you can only make GET requests through your address bar...

Here are observations when reproducing this:

1. It does not work on Meta.SU, simply because there is no chat for Meta.SU.
2. This does not work on posts you are not involved in, luckily...
3. Refiring this on my posts does not seem to work, ***the conditions are effectively checked***.

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
   Cache-Control: private
   Content-Type: application/json
   Set-Cookie: usr=t=$$$$&s=$$$$; domain=.superuser.com; expires=$$$$; path=/; HttpOnly
   Date: $$$$
   Content-Length: 0
   ```

   Note that I filtered away personal information with `$$$$`.

   Alternatively, it could use cookies to check whether the requests have not been tampered with. Seems the Stack Exchange developers do their job well, for a good reason...

Comment: If you and I get into a long thread here on this Answer like it's our own little sandbox, will Meta give us the "take it to chat" link? We could give it a try, but I don't know if Meta's running the same code as the main site.

Comment: I have yet to see a Meta comment thread (especially on Meta.SO) be moved to a chatroom. I don't know if this is by design, or if users ignore the offer.

Comment: Comment. For science!

Comment: @Spiff I'll try it (triggering a chat in Meta) with you.

Comment: @JeremyW Let's do this.

Comment: @Spiff bit of a time delay on my part - the Supermega Collider Inbox Widget didn't notify me.

Comment: wow, this helps me so much *sarcasm* and how exactly do you expect me to implement this code since I am not the webmaster?

Comment: @techaddict: This is ECMAScript, which is a client-side language and can easily be implemented given that it has to run on the client, which means YOU can run it. If you want to know how, feel free to ask a question on Super User because such information does not belong on Meta. Oh, and where exactly did I actually tell you to implement something? You must be trolling...